# How to get a nullable Type object from a Type object

Tags: c#, .net

What will be the best way to implement this method:

```
Type GetNullableTypeFromType(Type tp);
```

so that

```
Type tpString = GetNullableTypeFromType(typeof(string));   // Returns typeof(string)
Type tpInt = GetNullableTypeFromType(typeof(int));   // Returns typeof(int?)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public static Type GetNullableType(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsValueType && (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) == null)) 
        return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t); 
    else
        return t;
}
```

Comment: I'd add this between your two lines so that `GetNullableType(typeof(int?))` will work (return `int?`): `else if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) return t;`.  Also with this, passing `typeof(Nullable<>)` will give you that same type back.

Comment: This will still fail if you pass it an interface. You could make it more robust by changing the method body to something like this: `if (t.IsValueType && (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) == null)) return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t); return t;`

Comment: Another case I hadn't considered. Code updated as suggested; much cleaner than checking all the cases where NOT to return Nullable<>. :-)